# RSS is not working in google chrome using asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I have implemented the code for RSS in asp.net 3.5. I can see the RSS feed in my application in Firefox.

But I couldn't manage to load the RSS feed in Google chrome browser. It only shows the XML which I had written in my code.

How can I make my code Browser independent?

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>Demo Site</title>
        <link>http://www.ABC.com</link>
<asp:repeater id="rptRss" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <item>

             <% if (Global.SessionData.Language == Convert.ToInt16(Global.GlobalCls.Language.Arabic))
   {%>
    <title>
            <%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TitleAr"))%></title>

            <description><%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DescriptionAr"))%></description>
       <%}
   else
   {%> 
     <title>
            <%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title"))%></title>

            <description><%# RemoveIllegalCharacters(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description"))%></description>     
        <%}%>                     
    </item>

    </ItemTemplate>     
    </asp:repeater>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is my code behind. I have just bind the repeater and call this function to remove illegal characters.

```
protected string RemoveIllegalCharacters(object input)
    {
        // cast the input to a string
        string data = input.ToString();
        Cache.Remove("TitleAr");
        Cache.Remove("DescriptionAr");
        Cache.Remove("Title");
        Cache.Remove("Description");
        // replace illegal characters in XML documents with their entity references
        data = data.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        data = data.Replace("\"", "&quot;");
        data = data.Replace("'", "&apos;");
        data = data.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        data = data.Replace(">", "&gt;");

        return data;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your RSS code, or at least a snippet of it

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-build-an-rss-feed-with-asp-net/
from where the code is copied ... same problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the ContentType of the @Page directive to "text/xml" to indicate that the output of the rss.aspx page is an XML document. It's working fine for me.

Comment: You have to add RSS reader in google chrome. It will work for you.

Comment: neither for internet explorer